# How to get the innerText of rendered list item in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to get the `innerText` of an item in a rendered list, but accessing it using `this.$refs` doesn't seem to work. I've also tried to use `v-modal` and that doesn't seem to work either.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="simple" v-cloak>
  <h1>Clicked word value!</h1>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="word in wordsList" @click="cw_value" ref="refWord">
      {{ word }}
    </li>
    <h4> {{ clickedWord }} </h4>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#simple',
  data: {
    clickedWord: '',
    wordsList: ['word 1', 'word 2', 'word 3']
  },
  methods: {
    cw_value: function() {
      this.clickedWord = this.$refs.refWord.innerText
      // "I don't know how to get inner text from a clicked value"
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you've used `ref="refWord"` on the same element as a `v-for`, `this.$refs.refWord` is an array containing each DOM element rendered by `v-for`.

You should reference the index of each word, and then pass that to the click handler:

```
<li v-for="word, index in wordsList" @click="cw_value(index)" ref="refWord">
```

Then, in your `cw_value` method, use the index value to access the correct element in the array:

```
cw_value: function(index) {
  this.clickedWord = this.$refs.refWord[index].innerText;
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/cfjawyvv/)

---

Alternatively, it would be much simpler to just set the clicked word inline in the click handler:

```
<li v-for="word in wordsList" @click="clickedWord = word">
```

[Here's a working fiddle for that too.](https://jsfiddle.net/cfjawyvv/1/)

Comment: You're a genius. Thanks

Comment: This solution worked for me as well, this index part is very important, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be avoided when possible.) [Here is MDN document on that.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Now it is:

```
this.$refs.refWord[index].textContent
```